# Modifying a single file in a remote git repo

Tags: git

I have a use case where for for some specific reasons, I need to be able to modify a single file that exists in a remote git repo.

I'm trying to accomplish this without performing a full git clone for performance reasons as I'll need to perform modification on just a single file on many git repos.

Because I'm not sure where to even start, are there any suggestions or ideas on how to do this?

Is there a way to clone a single file from a remote git repo and then check it back in without having to perform a full clone?

Comment: You could easily do a shallow clone and a sparse check-out so that you only ser that file in the resulting working tree..... Don't know if there are other tricks to narrow it down even further.

Comment: Hey @eftshift0, I've just now tried out a shallow clone and sparse checkout. But it looks like, under the hood, that git still gets a full copy of the source from the remote repository. Many of the repos that I work with have code bases that are more than 70MB in size. So trying to update a single file across thousands of repos will be time consuming if I shallow-clone/sparse-checkout is used.

Comment: I see it can be narrowed down using `--filter`. Take a look at it in `git help rev-list`

Comment: Hey @eftshift0. With the tip you gave me about sparse checkout, I think I was able to find a solution. Though I hope that my solution won't shoot me in the foot. I'll post my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with the tip from @eftshift0 about git-commit, I think I've arrived at a solution that could work for me.

I executed the following commands to achieve the effect that I wanted. In my example, I'm getting single file from a repo on GitHub and I'm still able to perform a modification on that one file, commit that change, and push the change back to the remote repo.
On a repo where a full clone would have downloaded about 50MB worth of files, performing a treeless clone with a sparse-checkout using the --no-cone option, resulted in about 900KB of data being downloaded to my filesystem (which was far quicker).

```
git clone --filter=tree:0 --branch <branch> --no-checkout <gitUrl> <repoDir>
cd <repoDir>
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone <desiredFilePattern>
git checkout <branchName>
```

From this point, only the file that I wanted got downloaded and I can still modify that file, stage it, commit, and push that commit to the remote repo.

If someone thinks that I'm doing something wrong or dangerous here, please let me know as I'm not sure what the potential negative ramifications are by performing a treeless clone, committing to a treeless clone, or pushing a commit from a treeless clone to the remote repo.